# rss feed active and inactive jobs

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need a suggestion from you.I have a wordpress site where I am using a job rss feed to populate the db with jobs.The rss feed job url contains the active jobs always.

Now how can I update the db so that it will always show the active jobs.Shall I have to do something like this?

1.I have to fetch the job urls from the db and check if it returns 200 or 302 status code

2.Fetch the jobs ids from feed url and check with the db.If the ids are already there then update those ids with flag 1(active jobs) and rest of the ids updated with -1(inactive jobs) else add new entry

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the job update feed is being updated continuously, I would probably set up a background process (i.e. cronjob) to fetch the RSS and update the database (likely as you have suggested under option 2 above).  You could set the cron to run as frequently as makes sense for your purposes.

Your option #1 would seem a poor choice as you would need end up making a bunch of cURL calls or whatever for every item in the DB.

Your option #2 would allow for a single cURL call to get the RSS.  You would then extract a set of ID's from the XML.  I would then utilize a transaction on the database to first update all records to active = -1, then update the matching records to active = 1.  This is of course assuming you don't have a large number of job records in the database in which case, you might want to look at optimizing the update so you are not touching all the records.

Comment: EXcellent! I will be going with option 2.Also I can delete the inactive jobs which are older than 2 months and I can set that as a cron job as well.Many thanks Mike for your help.